# Log scale occasionally generating hundreds of ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a contour plot with a color scale that uses logarithmic scales.

```
scaleLog().domain([1.8e-7, 0.017]);
```

For most domains it generates between 5 - 9 ticks. But in the above example it returned around 70. The domain is generally unknown so I can't hardcode them.

Both `.nice()` and `.ticks()` don't seem to have an effect on the result.
Is there a good way to either limit the number of ticks, or set the number directly?

[image: desired][image: occasional]

EDIT:
I ended up resolving my issue by writing a recursive function that reduced the ticks parameter until a number below my maximum was reached:

```
 const logScale = scaleFunction().domain([domainMin, domainMax]).nice();

const getThreshholds = (requestedTicks: number) => {
  const tickscale = logScale.ticks(requestedTicks);
  if (tickscale.length <= maxTicks) {
    return tickscale;
  }
  return getThreshholds(requestedTicks - 1);
};

const thresholds = getThreshholds(maxTicks);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're seeing right now...

```js
const s = d3.scaleLog().domain([1.8e-7, 0.017]);
console.log(s.ticks())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

...is the expected result (the emphasis is mine):

> Log scales are also special in that scale.ticks **ignores** the specified count ([source](https://observablehq.com/@d3/scale-ticks)).

Therefore, a possible solution is filtering the ticks with `scale.tickFormat()`. For instance, keeping 10 ticks:

```js
const s = d3.scaleLog().domain([1.8e-7, 0.017]);
const format = s.tickFormat(10);
console.log(s.ticks(10).filter(format));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is correct, my own solution was to reduce the ticks param until my desired limit was reached. This doesn't give an exact number of ticks but at least prevents an absurd number.